# Rails | Elegant way of looping through and saving json post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, loops, controller

I am posting an ajax request on click action and the json data looks like this;

```
{"data"=>{"0"=>{"seasons"=>{
"0"=>{"from"=>"2017-01-04", "to"=>"2017-01-07", "weekday"=>"1", "per_day"=>"100", "weekly"=>"230", "weekend"=>"200", "available"=>"false", "check_in"=>"08:00", "check_out"=>"08:00", "sevendays"=>"false", "checkin_day"=>""},
"1"=>{"from"=>"2017-01-17", "to"=>"2017-01-20", "weekday"=>"1", "per_day"=>"250", "weekly"=>"323", "weekend"=>"300", "available"=>"false", "check_in"=>"08:30", "check_out"=>"08:00", "sevendays"=>"false", "checkin_day"=>""},
"2"=>{"from"=>"2017-02-01", "to"=>"2017-02-04", "weekday"=>"1", "per_day"=>"100", "weekly"=>"500", "weekend"=>"230", "available"=>"false", "check_in"=>"08:00", "check_out"=>"07:30", "sevendays"=>"false", "checkin_day"=>""}}}
}
```

I need to loop through the `from` & `to` fields if they overlap. I know there is a function so I can use it like, `(from1..to1).overlaps?(from2..to2)` if they overlap i should return json error, which is fine.

Another thing for instance, per_day can't be nil, how should I **loop through** to see any validation are not met. Then if eveything is fine save to database.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First of all, note that the input data in the provided example is actually already converted to a Ruby hash, not JSON.)

To loop through the `from` and `to` fields returning a Boolean indicating whether any of the date ranges overlap (assuming `x` is the input data):

```
require 'date'
any_overlap = x['data']['0']['seasons'].
  # Parse 'from' and 'to' into a Range of Dates
  map{|k, v| Date.parse(v['from'])..Date.parse(v['to']) }.
  # Sort by start date
  sort_by(&:begin).
  # Compare each consecutive pair of dates
  each_cons(2).
  # Return true if any pair has overlapping begin/end dates
  any? { |x, y| x.end > y.begin }
```

To loop through the input, returning a Boolean indicating whether any of the `per_day` values are `nil`:

```
any_nil = x['data']['0']['seasons'].any?{|k, v| v['per_day'].nil?}
```

As for an elegant way of persisting the input to the database if everything is fine, that depends on how exactly you intend this input to be mapped to your existing database schema, and the content of your existing Models (which you will need to include in your question for a more complete answer to this part). This will probably require placing the overlapping-ranges code in a custom [Active Record Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) procedure (you can use the existing [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) validation to validate not-nil).

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

**Validations come with Rails.**

For example:

> `per_day` cannot be nil

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord
  validates_presence_of :per_day
  ...  
end
```

Can you answer some more questions to help with the date overlap validations:

1. should there NEVER be overlap, or are they unique to a certain user/object/property-thing?
2. do you have a question about looping or mainly the group validation?